# Java return keyword analysis

Tags: java, return, expression, keyword, operator-precedence

Someone once posted this short piece of code.

```
public void method1() {
int value = 5 + method2(5);
System.out.println(value);
}

public int method2(int param) {
return param + 5;
}
```

My question is about the return statement and how it works.
As we send the value of 5 to method2, do we actually do:

`return 5 + 5` to `method1`, and inside of method 1 compute what 5 + 5 is?
So what I mean is that would it visually look like:

1. `return 5 + 5`
2. `int value = 5 + (5 + 5)`

which would do all the computations in the first method. Or would it send 5 to method 2, compute 5 + 5 in `method2`, `return 10` to `method1`,
and set value to 15.

So it would look something like this:

1. compute 5 + 5 in method2
2. return 10
3. int value = 5 + 10

I'm not entirely sure if my analysis of this is correct but the reason I am asking is because of some confusion I encountered with the `toString()` method.
When I overrode the toString method in a subclass, and called on the object class toString method (by calling on `super.toString()`), it returns a string.

I was confused on why that string contains a reference to the subclass, and not the Object class. So I thought that we would have a string containing the name of the object class, but instead I had a string containing the name of the subclass. My only conclusion is that this has something to do with how return is evaluated?

Sorry if this is a little hard to understand. It is kind of hard to put into words. Let me know what you guys think, and be well!

Comment: *"I'm not entirely sure if my analysis of this is correct but the reason I am asking is because of some confusion I encountered with the toString() method."* With respect, it doesn't make a lot of sense to ask a question about methods using `int`s in an essentially static manner when your confusion was in relation to `toString` in an inheritance situation.

Answer (score 2):

`method2` returns a single `int`. It computes 5 + 5 and returns 10.

Now, for the issue that got you confused:

The default implementation of `toString()`, as implemented in `Object` class (which you can see below) returns a String that contains the name of the class of the instance for which that method was executed (which is obtained by calling `getClass().getName()`). Therefore, if your class overrides `toString()` and calls `super.toString()`, it will get a String that contains the name of your class.

```
public String toString() {
    return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
}
```

Comment: Good of you to take a (well informed and reasonable) guess at the real question. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder There was no guessing involved. The OP stated the reason for asking the question. :)

Comment: Oh, I read that paragraph. But to extract meaning from it, well, I think there's some guesswork involved.

Answer (score 0):

It's all about **values** and passing values around.

- When you call `method1`, it calls `method2(5)`.
- `method2` takes the **value** 5 that it received, adds the value `5` to it, and sets its *return value* to `10`.
- `method1` receives the value 10 and the result of calling `method2`.
- `method1` adds the value 5 to that and saves the value 15 in its `value` variable.
- `method1` passes the value 15 into `System.out.println`, which converts it to a string and outputs it.

So `method1` receives the *result* of the calculation in `method2`, not an abstract thing that will do the calculation within `method1` itself.